# How to map embedded object arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, meteor

I have this array:

```
var arrayData = 

[ { "A" : {
            "score" : 37.91,
            "color": "red"
          }
  },
  { "B" : {
            "score" : 77.11,
            "color": "green"
          }
  },
  { "C" : {
            "score" : 45.35,
            "color": "blue"
          }
  } ]
```

I need to map `arrayData` into single arrays with the values of `"score"` and `"color"`. The `arrayData` can also have more than just A,B,C (e.g. A,B,C,D,E...).

So I need:

```
arrayScores = [37.91, 77.11, 45.35]
arrayColors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

I am using Meteor. How could I achieve that? 
Many thanks.

Comment: `var arrayScores = arrayData.map((v) => Object.values(v)[0].score); var arrayColors = arrayData.map((v) => Object.values(v)[0].color);`

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with meteor.it's pure javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each inner object is guaranteed to have only one key, you can do something like:

```
arrayScores = arrayData.map((item)=>(Object.values(item)[0].score));
arrayColors = arrayData.map((item)=>(Object.values(item)[0].color));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [ { "A" : {
            "score" : 37.91,
            "color": "red"
          }
  },
  { "B" : {
            "score" : 77.11,
            "color": "green"
          }
  },
  { "C" : {
            "score" : 45.35,
            "color": "blue"
          }
  } ]
  
 var result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
     Object.keys(item).map((elem) =>{ 
     acc[0].push(item[elem].score);
     acc[1].push(item[elem].color);
     })
     return acc;
}, [[], []]);

arrayScore = result[0];
arrayColor = result[1];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ChiragRavindra but am the one who did ;).. ha ha

Answer (score 1):

This is the very easy question and I recommend to you that please, refer javascript core function before post your problem here.

```js
var arrayData = 

[ { "A" : {
            "score" : 37.91,
            "color": "red"
          }
  },
  { "B" : {
            "score" : 77.11,
            "color": "green"
          }
  },
  { "C" : {
            "score" : 45.35,
            "color": "blue"
          }
  } ]
  
  var arrScores = [], arrColors = [];
  for(var index=0; index<arrayData.length; index++){
    var objVal = Object.values(arrayData[index]);
      if(!!objVal && !!objVal[0] && !!objVal[0].score){
        arrScores.push(objVal[0].score);
      }
      if(!!objVal && !!objVal[0] && !!objVal[0].color){
        arrColors.push(objVal[0].color);
      }
  }
  
  console.log(arrScores);
  console.log(arrColors);
```